# Riemann-Roch theorem for higher-dimensional complex manifolds

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, index-theory

Does an analogue of the Riemann-Roch theorem hold for higher-dimensional complex manifolds? (Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem is for algebraic manifolds, but not for general complex manifolds, right?)

Comment: Though the original proof by Hirzebruch was for projective manifolds, it does hold for holomorphic bundles over compact complex manifolds. In this form, it is a special instance of the Atiyah-Singer theorem, for the Dirac operator obtained from the Dolbeaut operator of the holomorphic bundle, see the Wikipedia page, or for example Roe's book  'Elliptic operators, topology and asymptotic analysis'.

Comment: In addition to the index theorem, you can also look at papers of Toledo and Tong who prove a Riemann-Roch for compact complex manifolds with coefficients in a coherent sheaf.

Comment: to add a reference to @DonuArapura 's comment, there is, for example, the following: Nigel R. O'Brian. Domingo Toledo. Yue Lin L. Tong. "Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch for complex manifolds." Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 5 (2) 182 - 184, September 1981.